# Would this function be linear, quadratic, or neither? (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

In regards to the length of the list being the input (n), would the time complexity of this code be linear because there is only one loop or quadratic due to "any" technically looping through the new array -- but not through every item on every loop? Or would it be neither?

```
public static List<Item> RemoveDuplicated(List<Item> listToFilter)
{
    var newItemList = new List<Item>();

    foreach(var item in listToFilter)
    {
        if(!newItemList.Any( i => i.ItemId == item.ItemId))
        {
            newItemList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return newItemList;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a List M and a Filter N so algorithm = M * N

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm complexity is the asymptotic behaviour as `n` grows large.
If unspecified, we assume the worst-case behaviour.
Here, that worst case is where every item is new to the list, such that `Any` has to traverse the entire existing list.

You nailed those parts: the outer loop executes `n` times; the inner loop has to traverse that list until it finds the element (we might assume checking `m` elements, where `m` is the current list size) or doesn't find it (checking all `m` elements).

In the worst case, the `Any` 1+2+3+ ... +(n-1) times, adding each `item` to the list.  I'm sure you recognize this as **O(n^2)**.

Assuming that duplicates are some fixed or bounded proportion of the original list, that expression is dependent on `n`.

Does that help the understanding?

---

Clarification:

The sum of the sequence `1 .. n` is `n(n+1) / 2`, or (n^2 + n) / 2.  This is dominated by the n^2 term.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having issues understanding whether the fact that each loop of the outer loop only leaves the inner loop the limited filtered list to go through affected anything. 

So the second list that the inner loop is going through being smaller at any given time (only reaching the full size potentially on the last iteration) doesn't effect anything? This would still be O(n^2)?

Comment: @MarcusDeCuir: That's right -- it's still **O(n^2)**.  When we can describe the time in a closed-form expression like this, only the degree of the largest term matters for the "Big-O" determination.  In this case, that term is `1/2 * n^2`, so the code block is **O(n^2)**.

Comment: @Prune Ahh, I get it now. Thanks again. I would have been racking my brain if not for you.

Comment: To avoid future wracking, search on line for some of those algebra techniques, such as sum of arithmetic and geometric sequences -- also how to determine the complexity of an algorithm.